# when changing deps, useEffect re-runs the setInterval inside itself. how to avoid?

Tags: reactjs, setinterval

There is a web application - a simple widget that loads local time from the WorldTime API for different regions.

The task is to fetch time from the server every five seconds.

To do this, I used setInterval inside useEffect , in which I put the function where fetch occurs. However, there is a problem - when selecting / changing the region, I have to wait five seconds until setInterval completes.

setInterval, as I understand it, is restarted inside useEffect when deps changes, when a new region is selected.

How can this problem be solved?

App on github: https://mmoresun.github.io/live-clock/

The code itself: https://codesandbox.io/s/codepen-with-react-forked-66iz3n?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call directly the same getTime function before setting the interval

```
  useEffect(() => {
    getTime(value);
    const myInterval = setInterval(() => {
      // refreshing with setInterval every 5 seconds

      getTime(value);
    }, 5000);

    return () => clearInterval(myInterval);
  }, [value]); /
```

As for your codepen example, you are continuosly calling the timezone api, because you fetch it inside the `SearchPanel` component. That's wrong, remove it.

Comment: Do you think its better to use useEffect with [] at searchpanel?

Comment: I've not spent too much time looking at your example, but why do you need it?

Comment: Don't mind it, both problems are solved, thank you :)